# Two Constitutive panes causing flicks in the animation.. javafx

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I have two animations in my program in a single stage one by one by changing panes

When i try to to do this

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane BP;

    public static boolean main = true;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


        try {
            if(main){
            isSplashed();
           }

           mainButtonSplash();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    @FXML
    private Button ButtonID;

    @FXML
    void ONButton(ActionEvent event) {

    }


    private void isSplashed() throws IOException {
        main=false;
        BorderPane bps = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SPLASH.fxml"));

        BP.getChildren().setAll(bps);

        FadeTransition fdin = new FadeTransition((javafx.util.Duration.seconds(3)), bps);
        fdin.setFromValue(0);
        fdin.setToValue(1);
        fdin.play();

        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(3),bps);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0);
        fdin.setOnFinished(e -> {

            fadeTransition.play();

        });

        fadeTransition.setOnFinished(e->{
            try {
                BorderPane bpss = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
                BP.getChildren().setAll(bpss);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


    }


    public  void mainButtonSplash(){

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(2));
        pathTransition.setNode(ButtonID);
        pathTransition.setPath(new Line(0,0,200,0));
        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(1),ButtonID);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(1);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pathTransition.play();
                fadeTransition.play();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

then the mainbuttonflash method animation which is over a button flicks in start (to me it look like that button appears and disappears and then the animation starts).

but when i directly launch mainbuttonflash method before the issplashed method it works fine

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane BP;

    public static boolean main = true;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


//        try {
//            if(main){
//            isSplashed();
//           }

           mainButtonSplash();

//        } catch (IOException e1) {
//            e1.printStackTrace();
//        }


    }


    @FXML
    private Button ButtonID;

    @FXML
    void ONButton(ActionEvent event) {

    }


    private void isSplashed() throws IOException {
        main=false;
        BorderPane bps = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SPLASH.fxml"));

        BP.getChildren().setAll(bps);

        FadeTransition fdin = new FadeTransition((javafx.util.Duration.seconds(3)), bps);
        fdin.setFromValue(0);
        fdin.setToValue(1);
        fdin.play();

        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(3),bps);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0);
        fdin.setOnFinished(e -> {

            fadeTransition.play();

        });

        fadeTransition.setOnFinished(e->{
            try {
                BorderPane bpss = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
                BP.getChildren().setAll(bpss);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


    }


    public  void mainButtonSplash(){

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(2));
        pathTransition.setNode(ButtonID);
        pathTransition.setPath(new Line(0,0,200,0));
        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(1),ButtonID);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(1);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pathTransition.play();
                fadeTransition.play();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

i want both animations to run smoothly one by one !

i tried to search but nothing helpful came out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why do you use separate `Thread` for starting path and fade transitions in `mainButtonSplash()` method? This does not make any sense, just start them in `FX Thread`.
2. You are trying to start several animation in the same time, that why you get flickering. Use `ParallelTransition` and `SequentialTransition` to correct handling animation.
3. Your method naming convention in horrible.
4. It would be easier to achieve your animation using `Timeline`, but if you need transitions then try this fixed code.

   ```
   @FXML
   private BorderPane BP;
   @FXML
   private Button ButtonID;

   public static boolean main = true;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

       try {
           final ParallelTransition mainButtonSplashAnimation = getMainButtonSplashAnimation();

           if (main) {
               final SequentialTransition splashedAnimation = getSplashedAnimation();
               SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition(splashedAnimation, mainButtonSplashAnimation);
               st.play();
           } else {
               mainButtonSplashAnimation.play();
           }
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }

   @FXML
   void ONButton(ActionEvent event) {

   }

   private SequentialTransition getSplashedAnimation() throws IOException {
       main = false;
       BorderPane bps = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SPLASH.fxml"));

       BP.getChildren().setAll(bps);

       FadeTransition fdin = new FadeTransition((javafx.util.Duration.seconds(3)), bps);
       fdin.setFromValue(0);
       fdin.setToValue(1);

       FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(3), bps);
       fadeTransition.setToValue(0);

       SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition(fdin, fadeTransition);

       st.setOnFinished(e -> {
           try {
               BorderPane bpss = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
               BP.getChildren().setAll(bpss);
           } catch (IOException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
       });

       return st;

   }

   public ParallelTransition getMainButtonSplashAnimation() {

       PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
       pathTransition.setDuration(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(2));
       pathTransition.setNode(ButtonID);
       pathTransition.setPath(new Line(0, 0, 200, 0));
       FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(javafx.util.Duration.seconds(1), ButtonID);
       fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
       fadeTransition.setToValue(1);

       ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition(pathTransition, fadeTransition);
       return pt;

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks man i learnt a lot,,And yes my method naming convention in horrible(LOL) thank you again  ... in your code everything worked fine but that SequentialTransition is not working properly splashedanimation is called but mainButtonSplashAnimation animates only when it goes to else {mainButtonSplashAnimation.play(); } not in that SequentialTransition st..